# Add an iPhone number to other iOS devices to receive iMessages/Facetime calls via the phone number?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, facetime

I bought an iPad for school and have been enjoying using iMessage and (especially) FaceTime, and I have recently acquired the new iPhone. So I'm wondering if there is a way I could add my iPhone's number to my iPad to receive iMessages and take FaceTime calls sent to that number, rather than having to rely on my phone 24/7 for these features.

Answer (score 1):

No,

iMessage and FaceTime are linked to your Apple ID so you will need to add your Apple ID to the device, not your phone number.

If you send a message from the iPad it will use the Apple ID, so someone can reply to your email address, if they send a message to your phone number it will only go to your phone.